# android coverflow height

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, coverflow

I m new to Android development

I m currently testing the android coverflow found here : http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

I succeffully implemented it in my project, however I cant find a way to give the widget the required width and height

my layout :

```
<view
    xmlns:coverflow="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.accessdev.myapp"
    android:id="@+id/coverflow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    class="pl.polidea.coverflow.CoverFlow"
    coverflow:imageHeight="150dip"  
    coverflow:imageWidth="100dip" >
</view>
```

changing coverflow:imageHeight and coverflow:imageWidth only affects the size of images but the widget doesnt fill the layout in height (it s like 10% of the screen and I didnt manage to change it yet)

Comment: Hey If you have got the solution please share as I am unable to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

as you can see in class Coverflow in method setAdapter, the adapter width and height are set to imageWidth/imageHeight, So modify the value of the two variables in parseAttributes method.

EDIT: I'm thinking you can modify the AbstractCoverflowAdapter to inflate an xml which contains an ImageView with the width/height set to fill_parent. That should work :D

For the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="400dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

In Adapter's getView() :

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageBitmap(your_bitmap);
```

Comment: If I hard code like this in parseAttributes method :    imageWidth = 480;imageHeight =320; I get the same problem

Comment: If you look in AbstractCoverFlowAdapter, you can see in getView this: imageView.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams((int) width, (int) height)); - that means that the images in coverflow will get the dimensions given in parseAttributtes(). It seems to me that the coverflow will only take the dimensions given there, unless there is a way to modify the code/layout to be another way...